# data to come in while and this incoming data to be returned continuously

Tags: c#, .net-core, signalr, signalr-hub

my purpose is, I want data to come in while and this incoming data to be returned continuously.

I put the AddValue ​​method in while because I want add data all the time.
and return the al the time

My Prblem is i call the GetValues in Hub but its returned to null
i try the so many various

```
 public class StockCaller
    {
        public static ConcurrentDictionary<string, Stock> _stock = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Stock>();

        public async Task AddValue()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                string[] symbols = new string[6] { "USD", "EUR", "ATLAS", "GARAN", "ISBNK", "AKBNK" };
                Random random = new Random();
                foreach (var item in symbols)
                {
                    Stock stock = new Stock()
                    {
                        symbol = item,
                        price = random.Next(100, 500),
                        percent = random.NextDouble(),
                    };
                    await AddValueAsync(stock);
                }
            }
        }

        public async Task AddValueAsync(Stock stock)
        {
            _stock.TryAdd(stock.symbol, stock);
            await Task.CompletedTask;
        }
        public Task<ICollection<Stock>> GetValues()
        {
            return Task.FromResult(_stock.Values);
        }
    }
```

My Hub is
I put the GetValues ​​method in while because I want data to come all the time.

```
public class MyHub : Hub
    {
        public readonly StockCaller _stock;

        public MyHub(StockCaller stock)
        {
            _stock = stock;
        }

        public async Task SendRandomCharacter()
        {
            //TcpServer can be useable
            while (true)
            { 
                var result = await _stock.GetValues();
                await Clients.All.SendAsync("receiveMessage", result);
            }      
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by opening a new thread.

Like this.

```
 public class StockCaller
    {
        public static ConcurrentDictionary<string, Stock> _stocks = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Stock>();
        public StockCaller()
        {
            Thread thread1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(AddValue));
            thread1.Start();
            //AddValue();
        }

        public async void AddValue()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                string[] symbols = new string[6] { "USD", "EUR", "ATLAS", "GARAN", "ISBNK", "AKBNK" };
                Random random = new Random();
                foreach (var item in symbols)
                {
                    Stock stock = new Stock()
                    {
                        symbol = item,
                        price = random.Next(100, 500),
                        percent = random.NextDouble(),
                    };
                    await AddValueAsync(stock);
                }
            }
        }

        public async Task AddValueAsync(Stock stock)
        {
            _stocks.TryAdd(stock.symbol, stock);
            await Task.CompletedTask;
        }
        public async Task<ICollection<Stock>> GetValues()
        {
            return await Task.FromResult(_stocks.Values);
        }

        public void ClearStock()
        {
            _stocks.Clear();
        }

    }
```

StockHub is still same but i am sharing share

```
 public class MyHub : Hub
    {
        public readonly StockCaller _stock;

        public MyHub(StockCaller stock)
        {
            _stock = stock;
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<Stock>> SendRandomCharacter()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                var result = await _stock.GetValues();
                await Clients.All.SendAsync("receiveMessage", result);
            }        
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "StockHub is still same but i am sharing share"?

Comment: @JeremyCaney oh my bad , MyHub is don't changed but i am though share here, Maybe someone is confused